# adding multiple rows with mysql- array?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, loops, implode

I'm trying to build a shopping cart by adding the products to the database table "shopping cart" and then get them moved to table "orders". I was told I should make an array of the rows in the shopping cart table to and then loop the `INSERT` query to put them in the orders table, but can someone explain how? I also read something about "implode" but I'm not really getting that either.

```
if(isset($_POST['button']))
{
    $query = "SELECT * from members WHERE username='$username'";
    while(list($id, $username, $password, $voornaam, $tussenvoegsel, $achternaam, $adres, $postcode, $telefoonnummer) = mysql_fetch_row($resultaat))
    {
        $adres=$adres2;
        $postcode=$postcode2;
        $query="SELECT * from winkelwagen WHERE username='$username'";
        while(list($username, $diernr, $dier, $aantal, $prijs) = mysql_fetch_row($resultaat))
            $query = "INSERT INTO bestelling (username, leveradres, postcode, dier, aantal) 
                    VALUES ('$username', '$adres', '$postcode', '$dier', '$aantal')";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it could be done simplier with a more complex `INSERT` statement:

```
if(isset($_POST['button']))
{
   $query = "INSERT INTO bestelling (username, leveradres, postcode, dier, aantal) ".
            "  SELECT username, adress, postcode, dier, aantval ".
            "    FROM winkelwagen ".
            "   WHERE user_name=? ";
   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
   $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
   $stmt->execute();
 }
```

Make sure `$mysqli` containis a valid `mysqli` database connection

I'm sorry I don't know dutch (is it dutch?), so I'¡m not sure I picked up the correct table and field names.... but I hope you get the idea